# Charset $ _POST param

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, cyrillic

When I put сyrillic text to `textarea` and submit form the at server I get collision charset param `$_POST['text']`:

```
string(571) "
ï¿½ Ð°Ñ€Ñ‚Ð¸Ñ Ð›Ð”ÐŸÐ  Ð¿Ð¾Ð´Ð°Ð»Ð° Ð² ÑÑƒÐ´ Ð½Ð° Ð±Ñ‹Ð²ÑˆÐµ
```

- All php files in charset **UTF-8** (without BOM)
- HTML page have meta tag:`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`
- In config framework:`$config['charset'] ='UTF-8';`

Comment: Do you have charset set in the form element? `<form method="post" action="/your/url/" accept-charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Yes there is, `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`. Form is sent by `AJAX`

Comment: In response i see: `<div></div>� артия ЛДПР подала в суд`. I tried disable editor jquery and had sent data via Ajax. At server came a full `$_POST`.

Comment: What jQuery editor are you using?

Comment: This: http://jqueryte.com/, So also I use serialize form and after execute AJAX. If you can, check please

Comment: What do you see in the network inspector when that form is submitted. Is it sending the correct format?

Comment: Yes, I have saw a request HTTP with params: `subject:Он потребовал от России 
text:<div></div>Он потребовал от России по.
typePost:article
add:1
type[]:19
type[]:2` It is a goodformat

Comment: Problem is not resolveed